# Override ActiveRecord::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails

some of my models has a "company_id" column, that I want to set automatically. So I thought to override some method in activerecord base.

I tried this, in config/initializers, but does not work:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize :init

  def init
    if (self.respond_to(:company_id))
      self.company_id= UserSession.find.user.company_id
    end
  end
end
```

#### Solution after Simone Carletti answer:

I created a module:

```
module WithCompany  
  def initialize_company
    self.company_id= UserSession.find.user.company_id
  end
end
```

And included this in the model:

```
class Exam < ActiveRecord::Base
  include WithCompany

  after_initialize :init

  def init
    initialize_company
  end
end
```

Is there something else that I can do?

#### update 2

Best practices says to do not set session related fields in models. Use controllers for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems here. The first, is that you are injecting a bunch of stuff into all ActiveRecord models, whereas it would be better to add the feature only to the relevant models.

Secondary, you are breaking the MVC pattern trying to inject into the model the session context.

What you should do instead, is to code your feature in a module, and mix the module only in the relevant models. As per the context, rather than overriding the default AR behavior, add a new method where you pass the current session context (dependency injection) and returns the model initialized with the required company, when the session is set properly and the model is company-aware.

Comment: The code still pretends that you have access to the UserSession inside the model, which is incorrect. You don't, especially if you are outside the scope of a request (such as a worker, mailer or the CLI).